# What is the output of this C program and how does it work?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    signed char a = 200;
    signed char b = 3;
    signed char c = 2;
    signed char res = (a * b)/c;
    
    printf("%d\n", res);

    return 0;
}
```

Output of the above code with brief explanation? since the res type should promote to integer, I thought that it would print -212, but the actual output is -84.

Comment: `200` is not a valid value for a `signed char` (assuming 8-bit char).

Comment: What do you do in response to the *Warning* for the assignment to `a`? `"warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]"`? Change your print statement to `printf("%hhd %hhd %hhd %d\n", a, b, c, res);` to see what is happening...

Comment: "What is the output...?" you wrote it "the actual output is -84". Please ask the question you want answered, something about promotion and/or the flaw in your (well decribed by the way) thinking. And find a title which matches that quesiton please.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you are on a platform on which [`SCHAR_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) is smaller than `200` (which is the case on most platforms), then, according to [§6.3.1.3 ¶3 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p3), the line

```
signed char a = 200;
```

will write an implementation-defined value to `a` or raise an implementation-defined signal. Most platforms will simply subtract the value `UCHAR_MAX+1` from `200`. Assuming that `UCHAR_MAX` has the value `255` (which is the case on most platforms), this means that it will write the value `-56` to `a`.

The line

```
signed char res = (a * b)/c;
```

is therefore equivalent to:

```
signed char res = (-56 * 3)/2;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
signed char res = -84;
```

It is worth noting that the sub-expression

```
(a * b)
```

will evaluate to `-168`, even if that value is smaller than `SCHAR_MIN`. This is because the type of the result is `int`. As part of the [usual arithmetic conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions), both operands get promoted to `int`, which means that the result is also `int`.

Since the result `-168` gets divided by `2` before being assigned to a `signed char`, it will have the value `-84`, which is guaranteed by the ISO C standard to be representable by a `signed char` (`SCHAR_MIN` is guaranteed to be equal to or smaller than `-127`).

Comment: Nicely done and nice citation to the standard.

Comment: "will evaluate to `-168`, even if that value is larger than `SCHAR_MAX`..." or when the value is smaller than `SCHAR_MIN` (which it is when `CHAR_BIT==8`).

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: Yes, you are correct that with a negative number, it makes more sense to reference `SCHAR_MIN` than `SCHAR_MAX`. I have corrected my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `(a * b)/c` seems to cause arithmetic overflow because signed characters can have values only from `-128` to `127` (on most platforms), and the value of `a` is `-56` because of the overflow. and `-56*3` is `-168` and `-168/2` is `-84`.
but in the calculation it performs operations on `int` values, so there's no overflow.